# send output of a shell command launched from script to a log file

Tags: php, bash, shell, stdout

I have a php page that creates a shell script that the same php page starts after creating it, inside I have one of many commands that I want to send the process to a log that does not work while others actually work....

```
<php
$scriptfile = script.sh;
$logfile = process.log;
$imgfile = image.ppm;

//this one works, it sends the output to the log file
$cmd ="Scripts/convert.sh file.doc > $logfile \\\n";
file_put_contents($scriptfile, $cmd, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

//this one does not work, it does not send the output to the log file and stops the process
$cmd = "&& for i in $(seq --format=%003.f 0 $(( $(ls -1 | wc -l) -1 )) ); do echo doing OCR on page \$i; tesseract $imgfile-\$i.ppm $imgfile-\$i -l eng; done >> $logfile";
file_put_contents($scriptfile, $cmd, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

$cmd = "/bin/sh  $scriptfile > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

I have tried the not working command from the shell and it does send the output to the log file, either this way:

```
for i in $(seq --format=%003.f 0 $(( $(ls -1 | wc -l) -1 )) ); do echo doing OCR on page $i; tesseract image-$i.ppm image-\$i -l eng; done >> process.log
```

or this way:

```
for i in $(seq --format=%003.f 0 $(( $(ls -1 | wc -l) -1 )) ); do echo doing OCR on page $i >> process.log; tesseract image-$i.ppm image-\$i -l eng; done
```

And here you have the way the shell script looks like after being created by php:

```
#! /bin/sh
Scripts/convert.sh file.doc >> process.log \
&& for i in $(seq --format=%003.f 0 $(( $(ls -1 | wc -l) -1 )) ); do echo doing OCR on page $i; tesseract image-000.ppm image-$i -l eng; done >> process.log
```

So my question is, what can be wrong, I've tried many different things already but no success unfortunately, any help or advice will be very welcomed!! thanks from now!!